# Trigonometric limit without L'Hospital rule

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I am having some problems for solving the following limit without L'Hospital rule or series:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arctan{2x}}{\sin{3x}}$$
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try a Taylor expansion at $0$. See what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to show that 
$$
    \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\arctan y}{y} = 1
$$
To do this, I would let $\theta = \arctan y$.  Then $\theta \to 0$ as $y \to 0$, so
$$
    \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\arctan y}{y}
    = \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}
    = \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}\cdot \cos\theta
    = 1 \cdot 1 = 1
$$
(the limit $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$ is one of the basic limits you can usually invoke without proof).

Now
$$
    \frac{\arctan 2x}{\sin 3x} = \frac{\dfrac{\arctan 2x}{2x}}{\dfrac{\sin 3x}{3x}}\cdot \frac{2}{3}
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I was not aware of the limit of  arctan(x)/x.

Comment: @user369151: You're welcome.  $\arctan$ is just $\tan$ after reflecting the plane through the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arctan{2x}}{\sin{3x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\arctan{2x}}{2x}}{\frac{\sin{3x}}{3x}}\times \frac{2x}{3x} = \frac{2}{3}$$